# PowerApps: Filter SQL datarows by non existence in Sharepoint List

Tags: sql, filter, sharepoint, powerapps

```
Filter(
  ClearCollect(
    tblSQL,
    ShowColumns(
      WRH_Artikelmaster,
      "Materialnummer",
      "BME",
      "Einheit_KME",
      "Status",
      "Materialart",
      "Verpackung",
      "Materialtext"
    )
  ),
  Not Materialnummer in Materialstammdaten.MATNR
)
```

Hi, for a PowerApps application I need to have a gallery displaying all those entries of a SQL table which do NOT have counterparts in the corresponding SharePoint list. I tried to do this with the 'in' and the 'not' opertor. 'Materialnummer' is a decimal from SQL and 'Materialstammdaten.MATNR' a number from the sharepoint list.
Do I need to convert these fields into text strings for this to work properly?

Comment: What problem are you encountering? An error? An empty Collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables are large or ever-growing, you likely want to rethink a different solution. These can be rather resource intensive types of Filters.

**This works:**

- Note the `Not()` syntax.

```
//Get the Sharepoint list
ClearCollect(colMaterialnummer, Materialnummer);

//Get the SQL table
ClearCollect(
    colTblSQL,
    ShowColumns(
      WRH_Artikelmaster,
      "Materialnummer",
      "BME",
      "Einheit_KME",
      "Status",
      "Materialart",
      "Verpackung",
      "Materialtext"
    )
);

//Create a collection of the filtered results
ClearCollect(colFilterResults,
  Filter(colTblSQL, 
    Not(Materialnummer in colMaterialnummer.MATNR)
  )
)
```

**Illustration:**

- This is with an actual Sharepoint list with `MATNR` Number-type column AND an Azure SQL table with the `Materialnummer` column as a `DECIMAL(4,1)`.

[image]

Comment: Hi SeaDude, In this case it just doesn't filter the SQL entries, which are already in the SP list. Neither does it load endlessly nor display an error. In the actual formula, the SQL entries are also filtered by other criterias and these seem to filter correctly.

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: Hey,

Please excuse me for letting you wait for my answer. Your suggestion worked, I am very thankful for that.

Cheers